# Pass xmlns check with Python

Tags: python, xml, post, input

I login on a site with with urllib,
but I get a verification page.
I don't understand what answer I have to send to the server to overcome the obstacle.
I think I understand that I have to send a POST, but by sending all the  content I don't get the desired result.
Should I send something the particular? 
thing?

I will be very grateful if anyone can help me.
Thank you.

Here is the gigantic answer I get after logging in...

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Working...</title> </head>
   <body> 
    <form method="POST" name="hiddenform" action="https://site.domain.com:443/"> 
     <input type="hidden" name="wa" value="wsignin1.0" /> 
      <input type="hidden" name="wresult" 
       value="&lt;t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse  xmlns:t=&quot; 
       http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust&quot;>
       &lt;  t:Lifetime>&lt; 
       wsu:Created xmlns:wsu=&quot; 
       http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd&quot;
       >2020-04-04T19:44:03.524Z&lt; 
       /wsu:Created>&lt;  wsu:Expires xmlns:wsu=&quot; 
       http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd&quot;
       >2020-04-04T20:44:03.524Z&lt;    
       /wsu:Expires>&lt;/t:Lifetime>&lt;  wsp:AppliesTo        xmlns:wsp=&quot; 
       http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy&quot; 
       >&lt;  wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa=&quot;  http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing&quot; 
       >&lt;  wsa:Address>https://site.domain.com&lt;  /wsa:Address>&lt;  /wsa:EndpointReference>&lt;  /wsp:AppliesTo>&lt; 
       t:RequestedSecurityToken>&lt;  saml:Assertion MajorVersion=&quot; 
       1&quot;   MinorVersion=&quot;  1&quot;   AssertionID=&quot; 
       _a0230c49-7fed-4469-bf9e-702b63ee7477&quot;   Issuer=&quot;  http://site2.domain.comadfs/services/trust&quot;  
       IssueInstant=&quot;  2020-04-04T19:44:03.524Z&quot;  
       xmlns:saml=&quot;  urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:Conditions NotBefore=&quot;  2020-04-04T19:44:03.524Z&quot;   NotOnOrAfter=&quot; 
       2020-04-04T20:44:03.524Z&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>&lt;  saml:Audience>https://site.domain.com&lt;  /saml:Audience>&lt; 
       /saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>&lt;  /saml:Conditions>&lt; 
       saml:AttributeStatement>&lt;  saml:Subject>&lt; 
       saml:SubjectConfirmation>&lt; 
       saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer&lt; 
       /saml:ConfirmationMethod>&lt;  /saml:SubjectConfirmation>&lt; 
       /saml:Subject>&lt;  saml:Attribute AttributeName=&quot; 
       implicitupn&quot;   AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>user@site.root.local&lt;  /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt;  saml:Attribute
       AttributeName=&quot;  accountthrottled&quot;  
       AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2017/04/identity/claims&quot;  
       a:OriginalIssuer=&quot;  CLIENT CONTEXT&quot;   xmlns:a=&quot; 
       http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2009/09/identity/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue b:type=&quot;  tn:boolean&quot;   xmlns:tn=&quot;  http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema&quot;  
       xmlns:b=&quot;  http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; 
       >false&lt;  /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt;  saml:Attribute AttributeName=&quot;  familiarlocation&quot;  
       AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2017/04/identity/claims&quot;  
       a:OriginalIssuer=&quot;  CLIENT CONTEXT&quot;   xmlns:a=&quot; 
       http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2009/09/identity/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue b:type=&quot;  tn:boolean&quot;   xmlns:tn=&quot;  http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema&quot;  
       xmlns:b=&quot;  http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; 
       >true&lt;  /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt;  saml:Attribute AttributeName=&quot;  authnmethodsproviders&quot;  
       AttributeNamespace=&quot;  http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>FormsAuthentication&lt;  /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt;  saml:Attribute
       AttributeName=&quot;  anchorclaimtype&quot;  
       AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2014/01/identity/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname&lt;
       /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt;  saml:Attribute
       AttributeName=&quot;  upn&quot;   AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>user@site.root.local&lt;  /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt;  saml:Attribute
       AttributeName=&quot;  primarygroupsid&quot;  
       AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>S-1-5-21-4287071985-2918672672-1443967343-513&lt;
       /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt;  saml:Attribute
       AttributeName=&quot;  primarysid&quot;   AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>S-1-5-21-4287071985-2918672672-1443967343-48981&lt;
       /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt;  saml:Attribute
       AttributeName=&quot;  name&quot;   AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>Username1&lt;  /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt;  saml:Attribute AttributeName=&quot; 
       windowsaccountname&quot;   AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims&quot; 
       >
&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>Username1&lt;  /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt;  saml:Attribute AttributeName=&quot; 
       authnmethodsreferences&quot;   AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport&lt;
       /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt;  saml:Attribute
       AttributeName=&quot;  groupsid&quot;   AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>S-1-5-21-4287071985-2918672672-1443967343-513&lt;
       /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>S-1-1-0&lt; 
       /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>S-1-5-32-545&lt; 
       /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>S-1-5-2&lt; 
       /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>S-1-5-11&lt; 
       /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>S-1-5-15&lt; 
       /saml:AttributeValue>&lt; 
       saml:AttributeValue>S-1-5-21-4287071985-2918672672-1443967343-13989&lt;
       /saml:AttributeValue>&lt; 
       saml:AttributeValue>S-1-5-21-4287071985-2918672672-1443967343-38388&lt;
       /saml:AttributeValue>&lt; 
       saml:AttributeValue>S-1-5-21-4287071985-2918672672-1443967343-22934&lt;
       /saml:AttributeValue>&lt; 
       saml:AttributeValue>S-1-5-21-4287071985-2918672672-1443967343-11501&lt;
       /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>S-1-18-2&lt; 
       /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt;  saml:Attribute
       AttributeName=&quot;  x-ms-client-user-agent&quot;  
       AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims&quot;  
       a:OriginalIssuer=&quot;  CLIENT CONTEXT&quot;   xmlns:a=&quot; 
       http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2009/09/identity/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>Mozilla/5.0 (X11;   Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99
       Safari/537.36&lt;  /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt; 
       saml:Attribute AttributeName=&quot; 
       x-ms-endpoint-absolute-path&quot;   AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims&quot;  
       a:OriginalIssuer=&quot;  CLIENT CONTEXT&quot;   xmlns:a=&quot; 
       http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2009/09/identity/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>/adfs/ls/&lt;  /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt;  saml:Attribute AttributeName=&quot; 
       insidecorporatenetwork&quot;   AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/01&quot;  
       a:OriginalIssuer=&quot;  CLIENT CONTEXT&quot;   xmlns:a=&quot; 
       http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2009/09/identity/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue b:type=&quot;  tn:boolean&quot;   xmlns:tn=&quot;  http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema&quot;  
       xmlns:b=&quot;  http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; 
       >false&lt;  /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt;  saml:Attribute AttributeName=&quot;  x-ms-proxy&quot;  
       AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims&quot;  
       a:OriginalIssuer=&quot;  CLIENT CONTEXT&quot;   xmlns:a=&quot; 
       http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2009/09/identity/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>WAPDMZMR01&lt;  /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt;  saml:Attribute AttributeName=&quot; 
       client-request-id&quot;   AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims&quot;  
       a:OriginalIssuer=&quot;  CLIENT CONTEXT&quot;   xmlns:a=&quot; 
       http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2009/09/identity/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>605e2c74-b033-4ca8-81c4-0380010000ba&lt;  /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt;  saml:Attribute
       AttributeName=&quot;  relyingpartytrustid&quot;  
       AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims&quot;  
       a:OriginalIssuer=&quot;  CLIENT CONTEXT&quot;   xmlns:a=&quot; 
       http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2009/09/identity/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>https://site.domain.com&lt;  /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt;  saml:Attribute
       AttributeName=&quot;  x-ms-client-ip&quot;  
       AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims&quot;  
       a:OriginalIssuer=&quot;  CLIENT CONTEXT&quot;   xmlns:a=&quot; 
       http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2009/09/identity/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>10.244.3.252&lt;  /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt;  saml:Attribute
       AttributeName=&quot;  x-ms-forwarded-client-ip&quot;  
       AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims&quot;  
       a:OriginalIssuer=&quot;  CLIENT CONTEXT&quot;   xmlns:a=&quot; 
       http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2009/09/identity/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>172.16.8.2&lt;  /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>85.203.20.10&lt;  /saml:AttributeValue>&lt; 
       /saml:Attribute>&lt;  saml:Attribute AttributeName=&quot; 
       userip&quot;   AttributeNamespace=&quot; 
       http://schemas.microsoft.com/2014/09/requestcontext/claims&quot;  
       a:OriginalIssuer=&quot;  CLIENT CONTEXT&quot;   xmlns:a=&quot; 
       http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2009/09/identity/claims&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:AttributeValue>85.203.20.10&lt;  /saml:AttributeValue>&lt;  /saml:Attribute>&lt; 
       /saml:AttributeStatement>&lt;  saml:AuthenticationStatement
       AuthenticationMethod=&quot; 
       urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport&quot;
       AuthenticationInstant=&quot;  2020-04-04T19:44:03.430Z&quot; 
       >&lt;  saml:Subject>&lt;  saml:SubjectConfirmation>&lt;  saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer&lt; 
       /saml:ConfirmationMethod>&lt;  /saml:SubjectConfirmation>&lt; 
       /saml:Subject>&lt;  /saml:AuthenticationStatement>&lt;  ds:Signature
       xmlns:ds=&quot;  http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#&quot; 
       >&lt;  ds:SignedInfo>&lt;  ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm=&quot;  http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#&quot;   />&lt; 
       ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm=&quot; 
       http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256&quot;   />&lt; 
       ds:Reference URI=&quot; 
       #_a0230c49-7fed-4469-bf9e-702b63ee7477&quot; 
       >&lt;  ds:Transforms>&lt;  ds:Transform Algorithm=&quot;  http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature&quot;   />&lt; 
       ds:Transform Algorithm=&quot; 
       http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#&quot;   />&lt; 
       /ds:Transforms>&lt;  ds:DigestMethod Algorithm=&quot; 
       http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256&quot;   />&lt; 
       ds:DigestValue>b1c+9bvSmPpFNvScSNJJpTbJ6LwIyo1RCvDVKY8QeuI=&lt; 
       /ds:DigestValue>&lt;  /ds:Reference>&lt;  /ds:SignedInfo>&lt; 
       ds:SignatureValue>LA1dNOW7en/qQ5Z90WZTZ0Asb+BHubYP2MwDdGYh0AjsJMl+YIzC66h8hQfASOThETLlkwCkyOF1bvghWzOB6ZO/GgCgsGaEf8/Ed38zJVis2oFyAJz5Jj9XJ3tHRrpbFQdNEO8NHC8e8QgSiMep1j96rnT7BNiNqpkbCLsC/BB9B/c2RS6tYXRZhKVneXQtZAMjywgd+OH0IiUbbpiBbK2+/X16UhyHUTWzs6CJI7Pv9SQY6rv+PIdAp0iZugOmmufyEuHgHcqjMW9w64HBONSRIwqJ7/blEKGGto1Urp4vxzpMjr7428AZikr4rG/09ublQZ+WEjhwgEZlh/BDUw==&lt;
       /ds:SignatureValue>&lt;  KeyInfo xmlns=&quot; 
       http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#&quot; 
       >&lt;  X509Data>&lt;  X509Certificate>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&lt;
       /X509Certificate>&lt;  /X509Data>&lt;  /KeyInfo>&lt; 
       /ds:Signature>&lt;  /saml:Assertion>&lt; 
       /t:RequestedSecurityToken>&lt; 
       t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion&lt; 
       /t:TokenType>&lt; 
       t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue&lt; 
       /t:RequestType>&lt; 
       t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey&lt;
       /t:KeyType>&lt;  /t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>" /><input
       type="hidden" name="wctx" value="rm=0&amp;  id=passive&amp;  ru=%2f"
       /><noscript><p>Script is disabled. Click Submit to continue.</p>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></noscript></form> <script
       language="javascript">window.setTimeout('document.forms[0].submit()',
       0);  </script></body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a form with three form fields on this page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="wa" value="wsignin1.0" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="wresult" value="(encoded XML)" />
<input type="hidden" name="wctx" value="rm=0&amp;  id=passive&amp;  ru=%2f"/>
```

And the website uses a script to post that form immediately after the page loads:

```
window.setTimeout('document.forms[0].submit()', 0);
```

This means you need to do the same thing.

1. Find out how to retrieve the form fields and their values from the response HTML.
2. Find out how to do a form post with Python. Doing that with urllib is certainly possible, but with a more evolved library such as `requests` [it's much easier](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).
3. Add those three form fields and their values and send a POST request to the URL in the `<form>`'s action attribute.
4. The web scraping library `scrapy` [also offers a feature for doing this](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login), which would make steps #1 and #2 easier.

*(No code sample, you should be able to figure it all out with the information above.)*